# Partial derivatives with respect to multiple variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

For any natural number $N$:

$$_t k_{mn}^1 = \frac{1}{m!n!}\frac{\partial^{n+m} k_1 (0, 0)}{\partial x^m \partial t^n}, \qquad (m,n=0,1,\ldots, N)$$

where $k_1(x,t)$ is a known function, for example $k_1(x,t) = x^5 + t^3$.

How I can write a code in Mathematica to calculate these derivatives?

Comment: @march There is no help about the higher order derivatives of functions of more than one variable in Mathematica! How I can do that?

Comment: @NoMan That is not true. See here (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html), third entry at the top. And see my answer on how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want to evaluate the derivatives at $(0,0)$ after performing the derivative. Otherwise the whole expression would vanish anyways.

In the documnetnation for `D` you will find that there is indeed a way to achieve what you want: `D[f[x1,...,xn],{x1,a1},...,{xn,an}]` successively computed the $a_i$th derivative of `f` with respect to its variables.

For your case that means you can use

```
k1[x_, t_] := x^5 + t^3;
k[n_, m_] := (1/(m!*n!)*D[k1[x, t], {t, n}, {x, m}]) /. {x -> 0, t -> 0};
```

which will give you zero for this particular choice of `k1`.